# How do I iterate through this object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iteration

Let's say I have the follow:

```
var test_data = {
'numGroup1': [[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]],
'numGroup2': [[(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17, 18, 19)]],
};
```

How would I go about iterating through it using JavaScript?

Comment: `for (var key in test_data) {}`

Comment: You do know that the values become `[[5, 9]]` and `[[14, 19]]`, right?

Comment: What is your expected output and purpose of iteration?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the parenthesis were causing that. I was just given data in that format.

Comment: @Josh Yeah, the comma operator causes the expression to evaluate to its last operand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test_data = {
    'numGroup1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
    'numGroup2': [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
};

for(var key in test_data){
    group = test_data[key];
    for(var num in group){
        console.log(group[num]);
    }    
}
```

@Ian is right... using () will not do anything but enter the last digit of each group. You should use a multidimensional array

```
        'numGroup1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
        'numGroup2': [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
```

Comment: Thanks combining this with the lan's response solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) to iterate over it

```
var test_data = {
    'numGroup1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
    'numGroup2': [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
};

_.chain(test_data).map(function(value, key) {
                   return value;
                }).flatten().each(alert);
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the underscore variation too, but I'll give it to Jay as it was the first one to solve my problem.